# Tkinter create shrinking circle on each mouse click, how to make it work with multiple clicks?

Tags: python-3.x, function, tkinter, bind, tkinter-canvas

I am creating a simple program which draws a shrinking circle of random color on every clicked location by each mouse click. Each click creates a circle of diameter 50 which starts shrinking till 0 immediately. Each click is supposed to create new shrinking circle.

However, my program stops shrinking of first circle after I click and create another circle. It completely shrinks only the last created circle. All others remain still. 
I believe the problem lies in function itself. It calls the same function which is not finished. How to make it run multiple times (on each click separately)? Or do I have it wrong with local and global variables?

Here is my code so far:

```
import tkinter
import random
c = tkinter.Canvas(width = 400, height = 300)
c.pack()

def klik(event):
    global x, y, farba, circ, r
    r = 50      #circle diameter
    x, y = event.x, event.y     #clicked position
    color = '#{:06x}'.format(random.randrange(256 ** 3))        #random  color picker
    circ = c.create_oval(x - r, y - r, x + r, y + r, fill=color)         #print circle
    print(x, y, farba)      #check clicked coordinates, not important
    if r < 50:      #reset size after each circle
        r = 50
    shrink()

def shrink():
    global circ, x, y, r
    print(r)        #check if countdown runs correctly
    if r > 0:
        r -= 1      #diameter shrinking
        c.coords(circ, x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r)      #changing circle size
        c.after(100, shrink)        #timer, size 1pt smaller until size is 0

c.bind('<Button-1>', klik)
tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: if you want multiple circles, you are going to need to use and array, not juste a `circ` variable

Comment: You may want to build the circles in a self contained class that when called will call a new class instance and run to completion.

Comment: @LioraHaydont actually an array is not needed at all. All this can be done in a self contained function with a nested function or a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you move everything into a class then each circle will be its own instance and will not interfere with each other.

Take a look at the below modified version of your code. It is probably not perfect but should be a good foundation for you to work with.

```
import tkinter
import random


c = tkinter.Canvas(width = 400, height = 300)
c.pack()

class create_circles():
    def __init__(self, event):
        self.r = 50
        self.x, self.y = event.x, event.y
        self.color = '#{:06x}'.format(random.randrange(256 ** 3))
        self.circ = c.create_oval(self.x - self.r, self.y - self.r, self.x + self.r, self.y + self.r, fill=self.color)
        self.shrink()

    def shrink(self):
        if self.r > 0:
            self.r -= 1
            c.coords(self.circ, self.x-self.r, self.y-self.r, self.x+self.r, self.y+self.r)
            c.after(100, self.shrink)

c.bind('<Button-1>', create_circles)
tkinter.mainloop()
```

There is another way you can do this outside of a class.

You can use a nested function and avoid global. Your issues in your question is actually being caused because everything relies on global variables.

Try this below code for a non-class option.

```
import tkinter
import random


c = tkinter.Canvas(width = 400, height = 300)
c.pack()

def klik(event):
    r = 50
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    color = '#{:06x}'.format(random.randrange(256 ** 3))
    circ = c.create_oval(x - r, y - r, x + r, y + r, fill=color)

    def shrink(r, x, y, color, circ):
        if r > 0:
            r -= 1
            c.coords(circ, x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r)
            c.after(100, shrink, r, x, y, color, circ)

    shrink(r, x, y, color, circ)

c.bind('<Button-1>', klik)
tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am still learning and not exactly familiar with classes, yet. But I see this is the right way.

Comment: @Blacho When I started I too was not sure what to do with classes but once you take the time to learn and understand them they are extremely helpful.

Comment: @Blacho I have added a non-class option for you as well in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, you do not need classes to solve this nor nested functions.  The key, as @LioraHaydont was hinting at, is you need to use local, rather than global variables:

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randrange

def klik(event):
    r = 50  # circle radius
    x, y = event.x, event.y  # clicked position
    color = '#{:06x}'.format(randrange(256 ** 3))  # random color picker
    c = canvas.create_oval(x - r, y - r, x + r, y + r, fill=color)  # print circle
    canvas.after(100, shrink, c, x, y, r)

def shrink(c, x, y, r):
    if r > 0:
        r -= 1  # radius shrinking
        canvas.coords(c, x - r, y - r, x + r, y + r)  # changing circle size
        canvas.after(100, shrink, c, x, y, r)  # timer, size 1pt smaller until size is 0

canvas = tk.Canvas(width=400, height=300)
canvas.pack()
canvas.bind('<Button-1>', klik)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where I don't disagree that this can be done without a class or nested function I do not see how Liora was hinting at local variables when he clearly said "need to use and array" assuming and is a typo for an. Can you explain to me how this is a hint towards local variables as I am not sure I understand?

Comment: @Mike-SMT, for me the key phrase was, "not juste a circ variable" which is correct.  The original design with a single, global `circ` variable was doomed.  A global array is a possible solution, but I think you and I agree that wouldn't be the best way to go.

Comment: True. An array could work like many other options but the simplest solution is probably the one you have presented. Personally I would use a class as when the code grows it will be a bit easier to maintain. That said for this particular problem you answer is likely the best/simplest option as a solution.